# Make VirtualizedList show as Grid

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-sectionlist

I'm trying to make something like this:

[image: Gird View]

The problem: The project was built with `immutablejs` and [according to React Native Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html#data), I can't use `FlatList` thus I can't use numColumns props feature of that component.
AFAIK, my only choice is to use VirtualizedList as the docs points out, but I can't figure out how to display the cells as a grid as shown above.

I've already tried to add `style` props in both cell and view wrapper, but none of the code used to align the cells, like the picture I posted, is ignored. In fact it was showing perfect when I was using `ScrollView`, but due the HUGE lag I'm moving the code to `VirtualizedList`.

Any help? Anything would be welcome, I already digged a lot on Google but I can't find **anything** about this.

Some sample code:

```
      <View>
        <VirtualizedList
          data={props.schedules}
          getItem={(data, index) => data.get(index)}
          getItemCount={(data) => data.size}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
          CellRendererComponent={({children, item}) => {
            return (
              <View style={{any flexbox code gets ignored here}}>
                {children}
              </View>
            )}}
          renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
            <Text style={{also here}} key={index}>{item.get('schedule')}</Text>
          )}
        />
      </View>
```

Comment: Take a look at [`FlatList`'s code](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Lists/FlatList.js) and try to figure out how did they implemented `numColumns` property. I don't know how you can achieve it but I guess it is a start.

Comment: I'm trying to do this right now, but the code isn't very clear. I was hoping for a already known solution.

Comment: With a small glance I can see that the most important 2 parts are the [`getItem`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/67ec8498f7a5e9d5bad193d3e960d12d1cf8e5ba/Libraries/Lists/FlatList.js#L534) which lets to render more than 1 item per row and [`renderItem`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/67ec8498f7a5e9d5bad193d3e960d12d1cf8e5ba/Libraries/Lists/FlatList.js#L617) which sets the flex direction.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, I had to cool off due extensive research. I'm going to take a look

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering my own question: 
I got it working by copying the FlatList.js source code from `react-native` repo.
Here's an example code:

```
<VirtualizedList
  data={props.schedules}
  getItem={(data, index) => {
    let items = []
    for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      const item = data.get(index * 4 + i)
      item && items.push(item)
    }
    return items
  }}
  getItemCount={(data) => data.size}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
  renderItem={({item, index}) => {
    return (
      <View key={index} style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
        {item.map((elem, i) => (
          <View key={i}>
            <Text key={i}>{elem.get('horario')}</Text>
          </View>
        ))}
      </View>
    )
  }}
/>
```

The number `4` is for the number of columns. The key parts are in the `getItem` and adding `flexDirection: 'row'` at `renderItem` in the `View` component.